# ADF Copy multiple files from a container folder using dynamic pipeline parameter

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, pipeline, copy-data

I have created pipeline parameters to pass storageAccountName, ContainerName and fileNames dynamically during pipeline execution time.

I need to copy multiple files using these parameters.
I'm trying to pass all filenames/specific filenames from a source container to filename parameter.

Any suggestion how to achieve this ?
[image: Source Container blob]

[image: ADF Copy activity - pipeline parameters]